# HiDPI Mode not respected by iOS Simulator

Tags: macos, xcode, resolution, xcode-simulator

I turned on HiDPI mode in my OS X El Capitan and now facing the issue: iOS Simulator screen shows only part of its contents. Please see the picture below.

If I turn HiDPI mode off then everything gets back to normal.

What can I do to have both HiDPI mode on and proper iOS Simulator screen?

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 and iOS 9.3 simulator.

[image]

Comment: This seems more like a bug that should be reported to Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is gone after installing Xcode 8.